# Back-end API receiving empty request body when making request from front-end

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs

I am building Web application on my localhost.

The front-end is Reactjs framework, running in localhost:3000

The back-end is nodejs + Express, running in localhost:4000

Now, I have created the API below:

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // {}, why it is empty?

    // create new instance, save it to database
    User.create(req.body).then(function () {
        res.send('success');
    });
});
```

The front-end part is:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Received values of form: ', values); // value is not empty, I have tested! So we did send something to the API

                const input = JSON.stringify({
                    username: values.username,
                    password: values.password,
                });

                console.log(input);
                $.ajax({
                    url: `${API_ROOT}/register`,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        username: values.username,
                        password: values.password,
                    }),
                }).then((response) => {
                    if (response === 'success') {
                        this.props.history.push('/login');
                    } else {
                        console.log('do not jump');
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tested the API by the postman, I can add users to MongoDB, so the API is good.

I have console.log what I sent to API, it is not empty, however, backend API receive d empty request body. I have already fixed the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" issue, so I think I do send something to the API, but backend API received empty request body.

Comment: Maybe you have to add a content type to your request? `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`

Comment: Have you tried adding the bodyparser middleware `router.use(bodyParser.json())` ?

Comment: @Tholle  You are so right! After adding headers, problem solved, thank you!!!

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a content type header saying what type the body of the request is it should work as expected.

```
$.ajax({
  url: `${API_ROOT}/register`,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    username: values.username,
    password: values.password,
  })
})
```